# Lucene query to check for greater than condition for a part of the field

Tags: lucene, kibana

Have a field called `queryparam` in Kibana which shows the query parameters for a REST endpoint and looks like `createdTime=1524456000000,limit=1000,sort=name`.

Is there a Lucene query to fetch only rows which have limit greater than 1000?

P.S. Not sure whether we need to parse the field to get limit value and check whether it is greater than 1000.